# Terraform: Send list of objects as input parameter

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

Pls. help me figure out what is correct syntax to pass list of objects as input for `terraform`

Type of the input variable - **list of objects**

```
variable "app_env_vars" {
  type = list(object({
    name      = string
    value     = optional(string)
  }))
}
```

Base on [tf documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables), I've tried several ways, but unfortunately, without any success, so, will be appreciate with any suggestion

[Doesn't work]

1. `terraform plan -var='app_env_vars=[{ name:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, value:"Development"}, { name:ASPNETCORE_URLS, value:"http://+:80"}]'`
2. `terraform plan -var='app_env_vars=[{ name=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, value="Development"}, { name=ASPNETCORE_URLS, value="http://+:80"}]'`
3. `terraform plan -var='app_env_vars=({ name=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, value="Development"}, { name=ASPNETCORE_URLS, value="http://+:80"})'`
4. `terraform plan -var='app_env_vars={ name=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, value="Development"}, { name=ASPNETCORE_URLS, value="http://+:80"}'`
5. `terraform plan -var='app_env_vars=[{name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", value="Development"}, {name="ASPNETCORE_URLS", value="http://+:80"}]'`

**Q: pls help to find the correct syntax for it**

Typical errors:

- Variables not allowed
- Expected a newline or comma to mark the beginning of the next attribute.
- Expected a newline or comma to mark the beginning of the next item.

**UPD:**

**Valid:**

```
 terraform plan -var=app_env_vars="[{name=1,value=2},{name=3,value=4}]"

 terraform plan -var="app_env_vars=[{name=1,value=2},{name=3,value=4}]"

 terraform plan -var='app_env_vars=[{name=1,value=2},{name=3,value=4}]'
```

But meanwhile:

**Invalid: (Error: Variables not allowed)**

```
terraform plan -var=app_env_vars="[{name=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT,value=Development},{name=3,value=4}]"

terraform plan -var=app_env_vars="[{name='ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT',value='Development'},{name=3,value=4}]" 

terraform plan -var=app_env_vars="[{name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",value="Development"},{name=3,value=4}]"
```

Comment: Could you please try this?
terraform plan -var='app_env_vars=[{name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", value="Development"}, {name="ASPNETCORE_URLS", value="http://+:80"}]'

Comment: Thx that take a look, but, unfortunately, nope - error: " Expected a newline or comma to mark the beginning of the next attribute."

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Im working on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format to put into library in azure devops is this one :

```
"["{\"name\":\"Andy\",\"address\":\"Paris\"}"]"
```

To get this value (in your browser) :

```js
const list = [{name: "Andy", address: "Paris"}]
const res = JSON.stringify(list.map(JSON.stringify))
```

With the res, in your editor : replace "\\" by "\" and wrap everything with "..."

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

The data type for name and value both are string, shouldn't one enclose the value of name in double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a couple of hours of attempt, the right format is:

```
terraform plan -var='app_env_vars=[{name="""ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT""",value=2},{name=3,value=4}]'
```

Main points:

- number type value can be not wrapped with double-quotes
- but aka string type, should be escaped with """